# Creating a kext to swap the shift keys with the caps lock key or the function (fn) key

Tags: keyboard-layout, osx-snow-leopard

I have a problem with the shift keys, and I would like to be able to swap the shift keys with the caps lock key. I didn't find any utility that would permit me to do that; the only solution I have is to create a kext.

Why doesn't a kext already exist to do that?
I found DoubleCommand, but between all the possible swaps it can do, there isn't the one I need. Are there any limitations that don't allow to create a kext for the purpose I described?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this one?

http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/

(Open source in case you're curious how it works.)

Comment: Thank you, Ken. I checked that utility once, but I didn't correctly understood which keys the utility was able to handle (I thought that with shift_L the author meant shift + L).